# Chrome "throttling" toggle on/off HOTKEY

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

I often:

- turn off throttling through dropdown
- hit refresh
- turn on throttling
  through dropdown

It's a bit of a task each time!  I can't just click the 'phone' button because that doesn't load the page properly when refreshing

Is there a hotkey to enable/disable ONLY throttling, not phone view, not dev-tools in general, but SPECIFICALLY and ONLY throttling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome fixed this.  They now have an 'offline' checkbox within network, and it is now separated from the phone view.

It's still 3 clicks, but no longer 5 clicks + scrolling/picking from a dropdown

What would be great would be a way to control developer tools from the page javascript, basically telling the page when to go offline.  This way, you could refresh and never touch the offline button, 1 click.

Comment: You can add shortcuts to go offline/online https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-107/?utm_source=devtools#shortcuts (Chrome 107)